# How to join two bigquery tables using python and beam coGroupby concept without directly passing the join condition in the query?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to join two bigquery tables in such a way that the data is read from table using query and inner join should be performed by beam coGroupBY key. How can I pass the primary key to join both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read data from two different bigquery tables in two different pcollection.
Then create tuples with your join key using lamda or map function from beam.
Once you have these two tuples for tables , go ahead and use coGroupBY key to join these two pcollections.

Comment: It works for joining 10 columns. But when I try to join 55+ columns it shows " 401 unauthorized error "